# LogOut not working properly

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have some trouble with logout on my page. i have a controller with this

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

And so a view called LogOut. I've put an href on it with a button :

```
  <li><a class="logout" href="~/Views/Account/LogOut.cshtml">Se déconnecter</a></li>
```

but when i click it keeps saying me your page couldn't been found etc...

But strange thing is this, if i put in my adress bar, the path to the LogOut view it works and i'm disconnected, someone knows why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give href like this instead of path to cshtml file:

```
 <li><a class="logout" href="@Url.Action('Logout', 'ControllerName')">Se déconnecter</a></li>
```

it will hit LogOut Action Method then will Render your view Appropriately

Comment: Or simply `@Html.ActionLink("Se déconnecter", "Account", "Logout", new { @class="logout" })`

Comment: well thanks Hardik, that works, i guess i have some progress to do with razor ! Your answer is good too Stephen thanks, not the first time you're helping me ;)

Comment: yeah, in fact that's proper way for generating links in razor

Answer (score 1):

You can set link in different way :

```
1) <li><a class="logout" href="/Account/LogOut">Se déconnecter</a></li>
```

`2) <li><a class="logout" href="@Url.Action("LogOut","Account")">Se déconnecter</a></li>`

```
3) <li>@Html.ActionLink("Se déconnecter", "Account", "Logout", new { @class="logout" })</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, stack is really a good community, always ready to help that's wonderful !